# Is it possible for a planet to be made entirely of water (even it's core)?

Tags: astrophysics, water, planets

I was thinking about this today...

Is it possible for a planet to be made almost entirely of water (H20)?  I'm sure that other elements would be in the mix, but I mean almost entirely made of water.  Even the core.  No rocky interior covered by water.

If so, what would the core be like?  I imagine the pressure would create something different than liquid water.

Comment: There are many types of ice you can't imagine: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Phase_diagram_of_water.svg

Comment: Water is not an element.

Comment: I know this, I just meant that I know there would be other elements included.

Comment: Thanks!  That actually is pretty spot on to what I was looking for, I thought it was a different question based on the title.  "In general, the core would be an exotic form of high-pressure ice, no matter what the temperature - water is solid at very high pressure, even if you elevate the temp a lot. " <-- that pretty much covers my question.

Comment: This would be a good question if it asked whether a planet fully made of ice is possible.  Then it boils down to the PT diagram, constant T line, moving to P=0.  Even then the answer is no.  It either has a vapor atmosphere or it is constantly losing mass.  Although, the latter case can still constitute a planet of sorts.

Comment: @lonewookie The title of your question certainly duplicates that linked post. On the other hand, that post is more concerned with boiling at the surface than with the properties of the core. As-is this is likely to be closed, but if you edit it to ask specifics not addressed in that other post, it would make for a good question.

Comment: The other question covers everything I was thinking when I asked this.  I was just a little confused by the title.  Thanks everyone.  :)